# How to find the link count of a directory

Tags: c, operating-system, posix

```
mkdir d
mkdir d/a
mkdir d/b
mkdir d/c
```

While executing these commands in terminal, what would be the link count of the directory d?

Comment: Are you looking for C code to get the link count or just a command? If the latter, `ls -ld` will give the link count in the second column of the output.

Comment: It shows up as 5. How did it end up calculating that value?

Comment: `a`, `b`, `c`, `.`, `..`

Comment: @kaylum: Or maybe rather, `d`, `d/.`, `d/a/..`, `d/b/..`, `d/c/..`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On POSIX systems, You can use the `stat()` [syscall](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to read `st_nlink` to get the number of hard links of any file or directory, **per what the filesystem containing it defines** as "number of hard links"

But POSIX doesn't actually define what "number of hard links" to a directory means. Directories cannot have hard links, so their theoretical hard link count is always 1.

Different filesystems use `st_nlink` to relay different information about the directory:

On Linux (ext4), `st_nlink` means the number of subdirectories of that directory, plus its special entries:

```
$ ls -F d/
a/  b/  c/  d  e  f
$ ls -a d/
.  ..  a  b  c  d  e  f
$ ls -a d/ | wc -l
8
$ ls -al d/ | grep ^d | wc -l
5
$ stat --printf %h d/
5
```

So if you run the commands in your questions, you'll get 5.

MacOS (apfs), on the other hand, defines it as the number of all entries in that directory, plus its special entries:

```
$ ls -F d/
a/  b/  c/  d  e  f
$ ls -a d/
.  ..  a  b  c  d  e  f
$ ls -a d/ | wc -l
8
$ ls -al d/ | grep ^d | wc -l
5
$ stat --printf %h d/ # with GNU coreutils
8
```

So if you run the commands in your questions, you'll get 8.